# How to pivot data based on the values in each row

Tags: r, dplyr, chi-squared

Say we are given a data frame like this:

```r
> dput(data)
structure(list(Location = structure(1:18, .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", 
"p", "q", "r"), class = "factor"), C1 = c(7L, NA, 3L, 7L, NA, 
NA, 2L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), C2 = c(NA, 
8L, 1L, 1L, NA, 9L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1L), C3 = c(3L, 1L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 7L, NA, NA), C4 = c(NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 
8L, 5L, 6L, 15L, 15L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 15L, NA), C5 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 8L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

The way the data has been recorded, we have a `Location` column, which represents a known grouping variable with levels `a:r`. Then we have columns `C1:C5`, which themselves represent 5 clusters that samples from each `Location` were classified according to some arbitrary variable. So the sum of each column tells how many samples there were from each `Location`. For example, `Location == a` had 10 samples, 7 of them were classified into `C1`, and 3 were classified into `C3`.

I want to create a contingency table to perform a Chi-square test of independence to see if `Location` and cluster assignment are independent. When the data recorded in this format, how can we reshape the data to do this?

Update:
Unless there is a simpler way to get a contingency table from the current format based on the values in each row (which the Chi-square test could be performed on directly), I would expect that we would have to turn this into tidy format, where there are two columns `Location` and `Cluster` and one observation for each original sample, so the output would look like this:

```r
#there would be 10 observations for location a, 11 observations for b, and so on
Location   Cluster
a           C1
a           C1
a           C1
a           C1
a           C1
a           C1
a           C1
a           C3
a           C3
a           C3
b           C2
b           C2
b           C2
b           C2
b           C2
b           C2
b           C2
b           C2
b           C3
b           C4
b           C4
....
```

From this we could make a contingency table and perform a Chi-Square test

Comment: What do you want to do about the missing cells?  Not to mention all the cells that are very small?  without collapsing somehow I don't see how you can make any sort of inference about `Location ~ cluster` you could conceivably test GoF on rows **or** columns but you have too little data to do independence or association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format and use `uncount` to replicate the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -Location, names_to = 'Cluster', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   uncount(value)
# A tibble: 251 x 2
#   Location Cluster
#   <fct>    <chr>  
# 1 a        C1     
# 2 a        C1     
# 3 a        C1     
# 4 a        C1     
# 5 a        C1     
# 6 a        C1     
# 7 a        C1     
# 8 a        C3     
# 9 a        C3     
#10 a        C3     
# … with 241 more rows
```